# Do I pay tax on money I send myself in another country?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, gift-tax, wire-transfer

I live and work in the US. I am a resident in the US for tax purposes, but am not a permanent legal resident (H1-B visa). I am originally from the UK and have some financial responsibilities there which require me to send money to my account there, although I am not a resident there. Is the amount I send myself taxable, either in the UK or in the US? I typically send around $5000 a year to the account. I wonder if this case is different from other questions as I am not gifting it to anyone, but sending it to myself.

Comment: Since it sounds like you've been making these transfers for a few years, I would consult a professional tax advisor, because if you *do* owe any taxes, you are late paying them.

Comment: This is definitely not taxable in the US.  I'd be surprised if it was taxable in the UK as my (very limited) understanding of UK taxation is that its based on income earned in the UK.

Comment: Are you asking about **additional** tax over and above what you have paid on your $5000 earnings? Because you don't get to *reduce* your tax payable because you have sent some of your income abroad.

Comment: No. I have paid tax on it already, it's what is in my account. I want to send some to my other (foreign) account. I know there are issues when sending money to someone (gift tax) but I was curious if this also applied to oneself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not. There's no tax on transferring your own money between your own accounts in the US, and to the best of my knowledge in the UK neither.

You do need to be aware of the reporting requirements though (In the US: forms 114 and 8938).

Comment: Thanks, I'm asked about both of these things when I complete my taxes with Turbo Tax, so my presumption is that this is declared

Answer (score 0):

Moving your own money from your left pocket to your right pocket is not taxable; be it literally or symbolically.

If you move it internationally, each country could have reporting requirements, and could get interested in the legality of the money’s source - but not for tax reasons.